# session_start(): open(/var/lib/php5/sess_ibfocfkgbpfaoimac34nkjotp2, O_RDWR) failed

Tags: php, session, symfony

I am trying to register as a new user on a Symfony 2 project, i've been working on. This popped up all of a sudden. It was working in office yesterday, and I've setup a similar setup at home. I got:

> Warning: session_start(): open(/var/lib/php5/sess_ibfocfkgbpfaoimac34nkjotp2, O_RDWR) failed: Read-only file system (30) in /home/projects/notes/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 406

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [session save handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler) needs to be able to write on the disk. The file system denies writing. That's causing your issue.

Change the [session save path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) to a writeable directory.

Comment: Any idea why this might have popped up suddenly? Havent saw this error before. Anyway, I tried `chmod 777 /var/lib/php5 -R`, still got that error. Set the `session.save_path = /tmp`, restarted apache, still same error (PHP tries to save still in `/var/lib/php5`)

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake it was redirecting me to the remote server ... but why does PHP not set it to tmp by default? `/var/lib/php5` is owned by root for me by default on Ubuntu?

Comment: Check your php.ini file, the defaults are configured in there.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP FPM and have set session_save_path in your pools, make sure you add a forward slash before the directory (absolute URL). This is what the problem was for me.

Answer (score 0):

M running debian jessi and i had the same problem for me a chown -R and a chmod worked