# what this error is due to session_start

Tags: php, session

My hosting sent me email saying

```
I have set the session.save_path = /home/users/web/b1475/moo.youraccount/cgi-bin/tmp for your account
```

then i found my website is giving me this error

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/home/users/web/b1475/moo.youraccount/cgi-bin/tmp/sess_718a8cd346244df6916f016eb315f19f, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /hermes/waloraweb006/b1475/moo.youraccount/db.php on line 4
```

and the db.php code is (it is database connection file)

```
<?PHP
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if ($conn) mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
session_start();
?>
```

what can i do then to fix this error :(

Comment: `/home/users/web/b1475/moo.youraccount/cgi-bin/tmp/` doesn't exists. Check it. Or check permissions.

Comment: Contact your host and ask him if he's sure that's the new path.

Comment: The path is invalid: It must exist and PHP must be able to access it (`O_RDWR`: Open for reading and writing.). If the file does not exist, it will be created. But if the directory does not exists, it will not be created. Please use the search, I'm confident this has been asked before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [session_start(): open(/var/lib/php5/sess_ibfocfkgbpfaoimac34nkjotp2, O_RDWR) failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542206/session-start-open-var-lib-php5-sess-ibfocfkgbpfaoimac34nkjotp2-o-rdwr-fai)

Comment: Hosting said "contact your website coder lol" but anyway thanks and i've fixed it with your all help. i found /cgi-bin/temp/ not exists on my hosting path however i thought it by default should be created by my hosting :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change hosting companies.

There is *no way* the session path should ever be within the cgi directory. Having it anywhere within the document root is very dangerous.

It's possible that devDrew is right and the path is bad - in which case the session won't work at all. It's also possible that you're using an old/expired session id - does it recurr when you try to establish a new session?

While you can avoid much of the nastiness from this (both fixing a permissions / directory error and avoiding a potential code injection backdoor) by using a [database session handler](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/session-handler.html) if your provider is making such basic mistakes here then they'll be making them elsewhere too.